# php length or count string

Tags: php

I am working on sorting some text, I want to count how many times a certain word occurs.

the text part like

> I have no **idea**, you got some **idea**, we will work out some
>   **idea**,  I have no **idea**, you got some **idea**, we will work out some **idea**,  I have no **idea**,you got some **idea**, we will work
>   out some **idea**

how can I use php to count how many times "idea" occurred, like word "idea" occurred **9**
I am confused on count and length.

Could someone give an example please? many thanks

Comment: Do you need to count _words_ or _substrings_? For example, should 'idea' in 'idealistic' be counted too? If 'yes', choose between `substr_count` mentioning answers here. ) Otherwise consider using `str_word_count` - or its regex equivalents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the script below. [str_word_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) will split the sentence into array of words, and [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) will assign the number of times each of them appears.

```
$words = str_word_count($text, 1); 
$times = array_count_values($words);
echo $times['idea'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Substr_count is your friend. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 0):

Using like search highlighting method (modified to work your way)

```
<?php 
$s = 'idea';
$text = "I have no idea, you got some idea, we will work out some idea, I have no idea, you got some idea, we will work out some idea, I have no idea,you got some idea, we will work out some idea";
$keys = explode(" ",$s);
$count = preg_match_all('/('. implode('|', $keys) .')/iu', $text);
echo $count;
?>
```

Comparing to substr_count function, this will count 'ideaidea' as two.